# How to get value from key from firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm trying to read the values from a firestore document, but I'm having issues. (React Native Expo managed workflow)

code snippet:

```
let db = firebase.firestore();
//let ref = db.collection(this.props.type).doc(this.props.phone).get();
let ref = db.collection("instructors").doc("0987654321")
let doc = await ref.get();
console.log("setStateFromFirestore");
console.log("data", doc.data()); //this prints fine
```

data object:

> "name": "blah"
> "age": "99"

How to get the age or name from such data object?

I've tried these but they don't work:

```
console.log("data", doc.data().get("age"));
console.log("data", doc.data("age"));
console.log("data", doc.data()["age"]);
```

What's the way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

As a property on the plain JavaScript object returned by [data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data):

```
const data = doc.data()
const age = data.age
console.log(age)
```

Or directly from the DocumentSnapshot using [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#get):

```
const age = doc.get("age")
console.log(age)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the doc.get("age") method and it works, thanks! But is there any realistic/performance difference between these two approaches or just a stylistic difference?

Comment: No real difference.

Comment: Hi @Doug, I'm currently trying to store Sign In with Apple user IDs to Firestore, but I'm having trouble with the retrieval process.  I've added it to the post as an edit, do you have any insight to this? Thanks.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, do not edit posts to add new questions.  If you have a new question, just post it separately.  I've rolled this back to the original question.